# Is there any benefit in creating a proxy for api consumption on 3rd party apis

Tags: api, proxy, google-api-client, mobile-development

I'm build a apache cordova mobile app that consumes a specific google api.
What i'm planning to do is consume google apis directly from the app.
Is there any benefit to create a proxy service that consumes google apis and have my app consuming the proxy api ?

I ask because it seems a common practice, but i don't see any benefit.
Is it a best practice or a bad practice ?

Comment: In general proxy generate "cleaner" code and force you to type your code instead of playing with JSON/XML

Comment: @Cedric hmm, you would build another layer just for that reason ? With current MVVM javascript frameworks you can keep a quite clean project structure. Also you can create javascript object instances from json responses.

Answer (score 0):

If yes maybe a legacy system, maybe yes to do transforms, but now in days, so many "more modern" RESTful API providers have pretty nice client libs. Seems like one more link in the system to fail if I was proxy, and extra load to deal with... (I wouldn't proxy requests to youtube or some storage account for large static assets).

I do find it nice to proxy my own APIs if it's not public. It usually helps to remove the whole CORS mess and eliminate any performance penalties from extra preflight requests, but most public APIs don't have heavy CORS issues since they are, well public and don't have limited allowed origin.

Even simple JS libs hosted on CDNs like JQuery, I usually leverage 3rd party CDNs if available rather than bundle and host on my own CDN through Azure or Google that I have to pay for.